# Outlook 2007 addins for filtering attachments accordingly to recipients

Tags: c#, outlook, office-2007

My question is that
I need to send attached mail to domain users and non domain users.
Domain users will receive .lnk of the attached file where as non domain users will receive physical file.

Now I am doing by capturing send event of outlook and internally divided mail in two parts for domain users I crated .lnk of the file and attached it and sent to user.
Where as for non domain users i attached the physical file and sent to the user.
But these things are done by sending two mails internally so I am not able to maintain CC, BCC information.
I need to do these things in one mail.
So it is possible in outlook addins to filter attachments accordingly to recipients.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this at an outlook level. I would be more inclined to doing this at the exchange smtp level by writting a sink.

Edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579185.aspx
http://msexchangeteam.com/archive/2006/12/04/431755.aspx
http://www.msexchange.org/articles_tutorials/exchange-server-2007/planning-architecture/understanding-transport-agents-part1.html

Comment: I have been think a bit more about this, If you substitute the attachments with link on send. And then at the transport level as a sink you capture the link and insert the real attachment back for the email that need to go outside you domain via smtp.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.But i don't have much idea about sink.
Please give more info how to writting and managing sink in outlook.

Comment: added a few links. I havent written a smtp one before but you should be able to read the message and re attach the real attachement for the external email addresses.